# Select Part of a Attribute - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the number only from an attribute (The number is dynamic). The button/anchor looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" data-removefield="collection" data-field="bc_inventorybundle_menu_product_0">Delete Dish</a>
```

The part I need to dissect is this bit **'bc_inventorybundle_menu_product_0'** I only want the number, for use in another function (Delete a LI with an ID of menuitem0_dish)

The code I use for selecting ID's elsewhere is:

```
  function getNum(element, attrPrefix) {
      //set prefix, get number
      var prefix = attrPrefix;
      var num = element.attr("id").substring((prefix.length));
      return num;
  }
```

It works great on ID's but I cant seem to get it to work for Attributes instead of ID's

So User clicks delete button **bc_inventorybundle_menu_product_0** then jQuery removes the **< li id="menuitem0_dish">**

I can't add an ID to the button so I have to use the attribute of the button. As I'm sure you can tell I'm a complete noob when it comes to JS/JQuery.

## EDIT

Having read all the answers I feel I may need to elaborate a little.

I think the biggest issue is registering when the Button/Anchor is clicked.

What I currently have is this, which I know must be wrong:

```
  $(document).on('click', 'data("field")', function(event) {
       deleteDish(this);
  });

  function getbutNum(element, attrPrefix) {
       //set prefix, get number
       var prefix = attrPrefix;
       var butnum = element.data("field").substring(prefix.length); //Changed as per suggestions
       return butnum;
  }

  function deleteDish(field) {
       var numbut = getbutNum();
       //Delete the UL/LI
       console.log("Num But" + numbut);
       }
```

Asides from all else this gives me an error of 'unrecognized expression: data("field")'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried selecting your actual data attribute:

```
var num = element.attr("data-field").substring(prefix.length);
```

Or:

```
var num = element.data("field").substring(prefix.length);
```

**EDIT**

First add a class to your anchor element (I'm going under the assumption that you have more than one of these):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-small delete-dish" data-removefield="collection" data-field="bc_inventorybundle_menu_product_0">Delete Dish</a>
```

Then:

```
$(".delete-dish").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fieldData = $(this).data("field"),
        num = fieldData.substring(fieldData.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);

    console.log("Num But" + num);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pj1bLh1/1/) to demonstrate

Comment: Cracked it :), took a lot of fiddling. Your exact solution didn't quite work for me however it definitely pointed me in the right direction so I'm accepting your answer. Hope it can help someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

Using the attribute name that contains your input should work:

```
function getNum(element, attrPrefix) {
      //set prefix, get number
      var prefix = attrPrefix;
      var num = element.attr("data-field").substring((prefix.length));
      return num;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zf3hmo4q/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
var getNumberFromAttribute = function(id, field) {
    var field = $(id).data(field);
    var parts = field.split("_");
    return parts[parts.length - 1]
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o6go79cL/

UPDATE

You could just pass in the element. The only purpose of the `id` was to select the object. So you could also just do:

```
var getNumberFromAttribute = function(elm, field) {
    var field = $(elm).data(field);
    var parts = field.split("_");
    return parts[parts.length - 1]
}

number = getNumberFromAttribute(anchorTag, "field");
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want to parse attributes with "data-*" name:

```
function getNum(element, dataName, dataPrefix) {
    var num = element.data(dataName).replace(dataPrefix, "");
    return num;
}
console.log(getNum($(".btn"), "field", "bc_inventorybundle_menu_product_"));
```